# how to find a tight bound for the function T(n) = T(n/a) + T(n/b) + n given 1/a + 1/b < 1. assume T(a) = T(b) =1

Tags: data-structures, runtime

I have seen before similar questions where the format uses a,b but the actual question provides a int for a and b. I have also seen questions that give the answer theta (n) but require to prove assuming a,b = [0,1).
how do you solve this question as its given?